# Change mouse cursor over vis.js network node

Tags: vis.js-network, vis.js

Is there a way to change the mouse cursor in vis.js when it's over a network node?  I'm looking to treat them as links to the object the node represents and have been asked that the cursor change to the "finger" icon to indicate it can be clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `network.canvas.body.container.style.cursor = 'pointer'` in a `hoverNode` callback and setting it back to `default` in a `blurNode` handler did the trick.

Comment: Please accept your own answer to indicated that the problem is actually solved when we see the question in questions lists

Answer (score 13):

For that purpose, first we attach **hoverNode** event of network that fires when we hover on any node of network.

```
network.on("hoverNode", function (params) {
        network.canvas.body.container.style.cursor = 'pointer'
 });
```

Then we bind **blurNode** event of network that fires when we bring house away (*blur*) from node. If we don't attach this event, you will see *pointer* on all over your network.

```
 network.on("blurNode", function (params) {
        network.canvas.body.container.style.cursor = 'default'
 });
```

you can see [documentation](http://visjs.org/docs/network/#Events) for further details.

Comment: This works reasonably well, but I had issues where if I had overlapping nodes (as in: I have physics either turned off or set to terminate quicker than will get a perfect solution), moving from one to the other causes the blurNode to fire and either it fires after hoverNode or hoverNode doesn't fire, but the mouse cursor goes back to default despite hovering over a (different) node.  (And actually, was able to trigger it when they are almost overlapping and I move quickly enough)

Comment: Based on current documentation, `hoverNode` and `blurNode` events get fired if the option `interaction:{hover:true}` is enabled.

Comment: @Foon I think your issue may have been related to a bug where `hoverNode` event was not fired off when transitioning from an edge to a node: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55748023/4572002 This seems to have been fixed in >v5.0

Answer (score 7):

Additionally, the hover flag must be set for interactions before the hoverNode event will fire:

```
var options = {interaction:{hover:true}};
```

Answer (score 3):

for me its work with 3 steps

1.Fired if the option interaction:{hover:true} is enabled and the mouse hovers over a node.

```
  var options = { 
    physics: {
      enabled: false
    },
    interaction:
    {  hover:
        true
    }};
```

2.hoverNode Function

`network.on("hoverNode", function (params) {
       network.canvas.body.container.style.cursor = 'pointer';
 });`

3.blurNode Function

```
 network.on("blurNode", function (params) {
        network.canvas.body.container.style.cursor = 'default';
 });
```