# Vis.js hoverNode not triggered

Tags: vis.js

There is a graph using Vis.js Network that consist of circles and edges between them.

Hovering mouse over a circle is supposed to show a tooltip.

Using Vis.js hoverNode and `node.title` (for tooltip content).

When mouse is moving from empty space into a circle - it always works:

[image]

However if mouse if moved over the edges neighter `hoverNode` nor 'blurNode` every triggered:

[image]

Is this a bug? Are there any possible work-arounds?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?